# Getting values from form using jquery selectors, multiple select fields

Tags: jquery, forms, select, selector

First of all, I had a hard time formulating my title, so I'm sorry for that.
Anyway, on to my question.

I have a big table of information, where some cells have form fields, specifically two  form fields for each row. At the end of the row, I have a "Save" link.

There are multiple rows where each row have their own sets of  fields.

I am having a hard time getting these two  values stored in a variable, since they are dynamically rendered, I do not have a specific id connected to each .

Therefore I would think that traversing the DOM upwards would yield me my results, but no, so far I am only getting "undefined" (I think I am on the right path, I just can't figure it out).

Take this code as an example;

```
<td>
<select multiple="multiple" name="paintings">
<option value="The Persistance of Memory" selected="selected">The Persistance of Memory</option>
<option value="The Great Masturbator" selected="selected">The Great Masturbator</option>
<option value="The Scream">The Scream</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="painters">
<option value="VanGogh" selected="selected">Van Gogh</option>
<option value="Dali">Dali</option>
<option value="Munch">Munch</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#">Save</a>
</td>
```

When the user clicks on Save, the selected values should be stored in a variable.
This is what I have tried thus far;

```
$("a").click( function (e){
    str = $(this).find("select[name|='painters']").val() || [];
    alert(str.join(","));
```

Instead of "find", I have also tried "parent", "prev" and "closest".
I have also tried specifying the selector to "select option:selected".

This works fine for getting *all* elements or just a single one, but when I'm trying to find the closest two  and storing it in two different variabels it won't work.

Greatful for any advice or help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to get an array of values: (yours isn't working because `find()` traverses down the DOM tree, where-as you need to go back up to the `tr`, then `find` from there)

```
$("a").click( function (e) {
    var selectValues = $(this).closest("tr").find("select").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
});
```

A fiddle for ya! http://jsfiddle.net/5tLxk/

Edit: Since you have a `multi-select`, you can nest another `map` in there to get all the values (Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5tLxk/1/)

```
$("a").click( function (e) {
    var selectValues = $(this).closest("tr").find("select").map(function() {
        return $(this).find("option:selected").map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
    }).get();

    console.log(selectValues);
});
```

Comment: Ah, of course!
I really have a hard time grasping the concept of chaining on all of the different functions. Thank you for your help - it makes total sense now. Have a great day.